# Which class should I use for a daily notification/reminder - AlarmManager, JobScheduler, WorkManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler

My goal is to have a daily reminder that sends a notification to the user, and I implemented this using an `AlarmManager`. However, I should've looked more closely at the docs, since they stated in the Android 10 changes that Receivers in Android no longer continue to broadcast after the app is killed, so save and optimize battery life. So my app works if it is in the foreground, but when it is paused or killed (home button or swiped away), then it no longer sends the notification.

So I looked into alternatives, but JobScheduler seems to be inexact and unable to be set to a specific time daily. WorkManager solves the battery optimizer issue but again, cannot be set to a specific time daily. So my question is can AlarmManager still accomplish what I need it to, or did I miss something about the other two options?

I have looked through a few threads with no success, and a common solution seems to be to register your receiver in the main acitivity, which I have done:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mIsReceiverRegistered) {
            this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            mReceiver = null;
            mIsReceiverRegistered = false;
        }
        super.onPause();
        MainActivity.activityPaused();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.rain);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
        video.start();
        if (!mIsReceiverRegistered) {
            if (mReceiver == null)
                mReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
            this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("AlarmReceiver"));
            mIsReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
        MainActivity.activityResumed();
    }
```

but no dice.

Here is how I set the alarm in the main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//alarm interval and trigger times are set for testing purposes
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000,65000, alarmIntent);
```

And my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.umbrellareminder">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.ajts.androidmads.fontutils" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
        <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```